# is Date.UtcNow timezone sensitive?

Tags: .net, datetime, windows-update

Assuming I have a computer that does not get windows updates installed. That means that the windows time zone changes that are sometimes applied using windows updates are not present on that computer.

will Date.UtcNow be sensitive to this (in DST and non DST) or will it work regardless of the updates?

Comment: If user set correct local time and current time zone have not correct UTC to local offset, then UTC time will not be correct.

Comment: So the only way to avoid this is to set the computer to UTC timezone I assume.